# AWS Glue - Capture XML string returned from SOAP in Python and store XML returned in S3 in parquet format

Tags: python, xml-parsing, aws-glue

I am very new to Python and AWS.

I have a requirement to write a AWS Glue script to capture XML string returned via `SOAP` in Python and then store this XML in S3 as `parquet` format. I have written the code to extract XML from SOAP, but finding it hard to capture and store the XML in Parquet format on S3.

Would creating a pandas DF from the `response.text()`be correct, and then use `to_parquet()` on it ? But I believe that would parse the xml and not store it as-is. Also, since it is a glue job do I need to use DynamicFrame in order to accomplish this requirement ?

How do I convert the XML text response into a Pandas DataFrame ?

Please advise.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx"

payload = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap12:Envelope 
                xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2002/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap12:Body>
          <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
          <Celsius>20</Celsius>
          </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
        </soap12:Body>
       </soap12:Envelope>"""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

The `response.text` above would hold the entire xml text returned from the SOAP.

Thanks.